# undefined variable in let*

Tags: variables, lisp, let

For some reason, when I try to C-c C-k the program containing the code:

```
(defun give-rank-vec (file-1 file-2)
  (let* ((cm-size (array-dimension (Swc (make-ff-array file-1)
                                        (make-ff-array file-2)) 
                                    0))
         (rank-dump-vec (make-array `(,cm-size)))     
         (Swc' (Swc (make-ff-array file-1)
                    (make-ff-array file-2))) 
         (Sbc' (Sbc (make-ff-array file-1) 
                    (make-ff-array file-2))))
    (dotimes (j cm-size) 
      (setf (svref rank-dump-vec j) 
            (/ (get-element Sbc' j j) 
               (get-element Swc' j j)))))   
   rank-dump-vec)
```

I get an error message saying that "the variable `rank-dump-vec` is undefined". I'm not sure why this is- I believe the backquote and comma is OK. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last reference to `rank-dump-vec` is outside your `let*` form. Move it before preceding `)`.